# Add instantiated validtor to input filter

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'd like to figure out how to add this instantiated file extension validator to the input filter for my flagicon element.

Here is the input filter code:

```
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $this->setInputFilter($inputFilter);

            $validator = new \Zend\Validator\File\Extension(array('php'));
            $inputFilter->add([
                    'name' => 'flagicon',
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters' => [],
                    'validators'=>[
                        [$validator]
                    ]
            ]);
```

And Here is my Form Element Code (right from an extended Form object)

```
            $this->add([
                    'type'  => 'file',
                    'name' => 'flagicon',
                    'attributes' => [
                            'id' => 'flagicon',
                            'class' => 'form-control'
                    ],
                    'options' => [
                            'label' => 'Locale Flag Icon',
                    ],
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$validator = new \Zend\Validator\File\Extension('jpeg,jpg,png,gif');
$file = new Input('flagicon');
$file->getValidatorChain()->addValidator($validator);
$inputFilter->add($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use array notation:

```
$inputFilter->add([
    'name' => 'flagicon',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => [],
    'validators' => [
        [
            'name' => 'Extension',
            'options' => [
                'extension' => 'php',
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```